# Should Teams have its own meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, stack-overflow-for-teams

I am OK with the new *Teams* feature, but it is not related to Stack Overflow as a free QA community repository. Maybe SO for Teams could have its own meta? What is the consensus about that? Do questions about Teams belong to Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: Are you asking whether part of the Teams product should be a meta part of the site (one per team) or are you asking whether all teams users as a group should have one place to put their questions *about* Teams?

Comment: More as a place for all teams users.

Comment: Whatever your opinion about this is, it is a very relevant question to ask.

Comment: Discussion about sub-sites of Stack Overflow has historically been carried out in Meta.SO and, before it existed, on Meta.SE. Two examples are [meta-tag:documentation] (which was a "community repository") and [meta-tag:jobs] (which is no such thing). Another thing to consider is that Teams profiles are linked to the regular Stack Overflow ones.

Comment: Was this question inspired by the blog post [How Stack Overflow for Teams Fits into the Community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/05/23/how-stack-overflow-for-teams-fits-into-the-community/?cb=1)?

Comment: As mentioned in another question, I personally think that Documentation made more sense on SO / meta unlike Teams / Careers.

Comment: Learn about the *Ignore tags* feature. It is awesome to not be bothered anymore by topics you're not interested in / annoys the heck out users. All that is left is to complain now and then about tags not being applied swiftly ...

Comment: @duplode Teams is not a sub-site, it is a private instance each with a private user base.

Comment: @rath Though I am not a Teams user, from what I gather Teams questions show up through extra feeds in the SO interface, so if anything it is more integrated with the main site than a proper sub-site would be. That also matches Jon Ericsson's remark in the blog post linked to above: "Instead of going to a separate site, Stack Overflow for Teams puts your private Q&A on the site most programmers visit routinely as a part of their job."

Comment: @duplode That may be the case, but the fact remains public users won't see any Teams instances they're not members of, so Teams should't be considered a sub-site as it's not available to the public

Answer (score 19):

Since Teams is a new thing, and still in flux, the wider community can benefit of knowing what are the issues or features before jumping into the ship. Also, given that the Teams features do interact with the public site, I don't see why the SE team should have to visit yet another site (remember, they have to monitor all the +100 meta sites). Tags should work just fine for this.

Comment: Yes, these Q&As are going to be useful to all of literally 4 people who're using teams right now. I don't think the usefulness of the question is a legitimate reason but I do get the added strain on CMs. The best thing to do would be to add the tag to your ignore list and move on. Let JonH and Catija keep asking their questions in peace for the people who actually want to read them ;)

Comment: Having 1 team meta site would allow to have all Teams-specific questions on one Meta instead of having to monitor 100 meta sites.

Comment: @Cœur they already have that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look at the specific tag filter's trick.

Answer (score 7):

I think the real question to ask is *how well has Meta scaled for feature request and support needs over the years?* The answer to that is for another discussion, but we've acknowledged that we're going to need something more robust as time rolls on.

Stack Overflow for teams *is* a private product for the most part, but so are Talent and Display Ads, and we haven't encountered anything *too* disruptive in the process of supporting them here. Until we overhaul meta to make features bugs and support depart from the general Q&A functionality for their own purposes, Meta still remains a fine place to handle it.

On our end, we need to come up with better systems to make sure the bug backlog gets cleared and stuff doesn't fall through the cracks, but that's ***in general***, (you might have noticed Shog9 fixing quite a few lingering bugs as of late). It's not fair if folks *only* see stuff getting fixed in the new shiny things, which is why we're attacking all of it. We can't let the place burn down while we figure out how to put the fires out, so to say.

What we ask from everyone else is to remember that teams can organize and run things *any way they want*, so if you see what looks like a really silly feature request, please double-check that it's actually intended for public Q&A (and not something teams related) before you break out the rubber chickens and silly string.

And while an overhaul *is* needed, we're fine for quite a while, so there's no reason to knee-jerk in an attempt to make things better in the short term since they're generally fine for now, and will continue to be fine - it's better to use the time to put more thought into what meta could be doing better, and how to help it accomplish that stuff through changes in how it handles particular requests (features, bugs, discussions, etc).

Comment: Thank you Tim to take the time to answer to my question. I know you, Shog9, and many others, want to make internet a better world... Still.

Answer (score 5):

I'll start with a nitpic - Teams is not a feature. It's a product. This is important to keep in mind. It's also worth to separate the community of SO and communities hosted on Teams. The former is public and the latter private, and as such are very different audiences with different needs.

There will be things for Teams that go completely against the nature of SO. These questions will get downvoted, or will veer off subject, if they stay on the main Meta, and it'll happen for something other than their appropriateness for a paid product. It'll happen because most users have SO proper in their heads and don't realize that Teams is (allow me to say this again) a paid product.

For example, I asked about a feature I'd like to see in Teams; it got downvoted because Meta users didn't like the feature. Well, I don't care, I'm not trying to mess with their site, I'm trying to make mine better. I don't want to interact with people who don't have an interest in Teams, and they are probably better off not seeing these questions on their feed, to keep in line with their own interests.

Braiam mentioned the need to monitor yet another Meta site. I don't see why we should worry about that, if they stretch themselves too thin they can always adjust their pricing.

Closing, I think it's worth directing all Teams questions to a more appropriate place, even if it means something other than a Meta site. Many questions will be answerable by staff only, and the community's input is irrelevant. When I ask about Teams I'm not interested about the community's opinion, because the only community I care about is... mine. The one I'll be hosting on Teams. Not SO Meta, not anything else  :)